# Haskell - Unix domain socket bottleneck from PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, unix, haskell, unix-socket

I am writing a microservice framework to work alongside a PHP site. I have written it and tested it on my local computer (OSX) and it works very well. It will take data, read it as a ByteString, parse it into Haskell data with Aeson and perform specific actions on that data. I have it communicating over Unix domain sockets.

I tested it on my local system by doing a `curl` to a localhost php file that communicates with the Haskell program. It was able to send/receive/print information 10,000 times in about 2 minutes.

When I moved this over to the production server and implemented the exact same thing with PHP on that side, some weird things started to happen. The Haskell program runs, however it gets caught somewhere and just seems to hang for an increasing amount of time. First it hangs for 0.1 seconds longer than it should, and it just keeps going up and up. After about a minute of receiving 10+ requests/second the hangtime is almost 8 seconds. I made sure this wasn't the database being slow for whatever reason by comparing the time Haskell was called via the socket to the current time (right before the database call).

Here is my main function:

```
import Network.Socket

main :: IO ()
main = do
    removeSocketFile socketName
    resource <- defaultResources
    withSocketsDo $ do
        sock <- socket AF_UNIX Stream 0
        bind sock $ SockAddrUnix socketName
        chmodSocket socketName
        putStrLn $ "Created socket file at " ++ socketName
        listen sock maxListenQueue
        catch
            (handleSocket sock resource)
            (\e -> do
                putStrLn $ show (e :: AsyncException)
                close sock
                putStrLn "Closed socket"
                removeSocketFile socketName
            )
```

And this is the code that handles the sockets and everything:

```
import Network.Socket
import Network.Socket.ByteString as NB
import Data.ByteString as B
import Data.Char as C

handleSocket :: Socket -> ServerResources -> IO ()
handleSocket sock resource = do
    (conn,_) <- accept sock
    forkIO $ processConn conn resource
    handleSocket sock resource

processConn :: Socket -> ServerResources -> IO ()
processConn conn resource = do
    msg <- NB.recv conn 2048
    unless (B.null msg) $ do
        let (cmd, payload) = B.break (== (fromIntegral $ C.ord ':')) msg
        delegate cmd (B.drop 1 payload) conn resource
        return ()
```

Does anyone see anything wrong here that would cause the program to behave like I described above? The strange thing is that it doesn't break at all when I run it on OSX, but when I put it onto Ubuntu 15.10 things don't go the way they should.

I think it can be isolated to these functions because they are the only ones dealing with any sort of IO aside from the database (which I already concluded was not the problem).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose it could be some kind of memory leak that makes it take more and more garbage collector time on each request... Have you tried looking at the runtime statistics output? (`+RTS -s`)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I compiled with RTS on the production server and my own computer. The left is the production server after handling about 4300 requests and the right is my own computer after handling about 500 requests (test DB): http://puu.sh/pTvvQ.png
At the top of the production shell session, you can see the time the socket was called compared to the time the database was called. It was lagging at the time that I can canceled it, but for about 4 minutes it ran almost perfectly, which hasn't happened before. For those 4 minutes, if it lagged behind, it would catch up in a few seconds.

Comment: OK, so it looks like GC is minuscule in both cases. So that rules that out...

Comment: Yeah it's really confusing. I am going to try removing GHC entirely and reinstalling it from source. My friend was having issues with GHC on Ubuntu when it used 100% CPU for absolutely no reason one time.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid So I reinstalled GHC and I'm still seeing the same issue. I am led to believe this is a PHP socket problem now. When I turn off the Haskell microservice program and revert it back to doing things purely in PHP, the Haskell program suddenly handles 100 (supposedly) queued requests in 1 second. So that leads me to believe that PHP is limiting the number of connections to a socket for some reason? Or at least doing something evil when a new socket connection is created. Not sure at all.

Comment: You have to close all accepted sockets too, not only main socket or you will reach OS limit for opened descriptors. This is pretty same as TCP sockets. Also note: UNIX sockets could be used in datagram mode (udp like mode) in that case you don't need to accept new socket from it. For more info refer to [man unix](http://linux.die.net/man/7/unix)

Comment: Yes, I close every socket that I accept once I am done with it. The functions that actually deal with the sockets and return data aren't show in my post because that would add some unnecessary complexity and would go deeper than the problem requires (since the hanging happens before those functions). And I can see about using datagram mode for it at some point. I don't think that will solve my problem though. It may be that php-fpm is not cleaning up sockets until it garbage collects or something along those lines.